# jQuery datepicker convert to date() on PHP

Tags: php, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a script that saves a date like this.

```
$date = date('i')+50;
```

When I store this on my database, I got something like 1382851302 which works great to compare for past and future just using > or <.

In other part of the script for the admin I'm using a filter based on jQuery datepicker. The problem is I can't convert the date selected there to the same `date()` format so I can compare the date, I think time is somehow involved here (i) and well I can't.

here is my bad try.

```
$iniciopub = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['iniciopub']));
 
$finpub = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['finpub']));
```

This is not working.. (it just store "1970" )

if I try this..

```
  $iniciopub = date($_POST['iniciopub']);
     
    $finpub = date($_POST['finpub']);
```

I just save the day, I think because the format is like 00/00/0000 so the / is "cutting" the value because I can just save int. in the database as you can see in the format I need, I just need numbers.

Really lost on this, sorry if this is a fool question.

I'm studying so don't be so hard.

EDIT:
Ok this is my code now I'm using mktime()

```
$iniciodate = str_replace("/",",",$_POST['iniciopub']);
           $iniciopub = mktime(0,0,0,$iniciodate);
           
           $findate = str_replace("/",",",$_POST['finpub']);
           $finpub = mktime(0,0,0,$findate);
```

This saves this to timestamps for 10/27/2013 = 1382824800 but the same for 10/31/2013

Also I'm using this format, I have not problem with it

```
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
```

This is now set in datepicker jQuery UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `$iniciopub` has value `1970-01-01` because `strtotime()` returned `false`:

```
var_dump( strtotime($_POST['iniciopub']) );
```

Take a look at [supported date and time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). If you are saying that you have format like `00/00/0000` in `$_POST`, then strtotime asumes this is american month, day and year (`mm/dd/yyyy`), like it states [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

If inputed format `00/00/0000` is `dd/mm/yyyy` then the easiest method would be to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or `str_replace('/', '-', 'dd/mm/yyyy');` to make it european date format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

**Question update**

This code is just wrong:

```
$iniciodate = str_replace("/",",",$_POST['iniciopub']);
$iniciopub = mktime(0,0,0,$iniciodate);
```

[`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) has 6 parameters (7th is `is_dst` wthich doesn't matter now). You cannot use `$iniciodate` like that, because you are inputing only 4th parameter into `mktime()` function, and not 4th, 5th and 6th as you might think.

`mktime(0,0,0,'10,27,2013');` is not the same as `mktime(0,0,0,10,27,2013);` or `` `mktime(0,0,0,'10','27','2013'); ``. The reason why date `10/27/2013` and `10/31/2013` return same timestamp is because in both cases, when you cast string `10,27,2013` and `10,31,2013` to integer (4th parameter), you get `10`. See:

```
$v = '10,27,2013'; var_dump( (int)$v ); # int(10)
$v = '10,31,2013'; var_dump( (int)$v ); # int(10)
```

And because of that, your call is the same if you would call `mktime()` like:

```
var_dump(  mktime(0,0,0,10) ); # int(1382832000)
```

If you would have error_reporting on (put `error_reporting(-1);` on the beggining of the php file), you would see, that after calling `mktime(0,0,0,$iniciodate)` you would get NOTICE:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in file.php on line XX

Since `10/27/2013` and `10/31/2013` are standard american date formats, you can just use `strtotime()` instead of `mktime()` to convert date to timestamps:

```
var_dump( strtotime('10/27/2013') ); # int(1382832000)
var_dump( strtotime('10/31/2013') ); # int(1383177600)
```

---

You asked in the comments: *`if i store a date as dd-mm-yyyy. how can i compare the date with other date. am i doing fine storing as timestamp?`*

Yes, you can store them as timestamp. But I haven't used timestamp in my code for ages, I am storing dates as YYYY-MM-DD; in RDBMS this is kinda best practice.

Comment: or if i store a date as dd-mm-yyyy.  how can i compare the date with other date. am i doing fine storing as timestamp?

Comment: @MonchoChavez: np mate, glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Better way not conver to mktime in PHP - save data as mktime already:

```
function mdf_init_calendars() {
jQuery(".mdf_calendar").datepicker(
        {
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, self) {
                var date = new Date(parseInt(self.currentYear, 10), parseInt(self.currentMonth, 10), parseInt(self.currentDay, 10), 23, 59, 59);
                var mktime = (date.getTime() / 1000);
                jQuery(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val(mktime);
            }
        }
);
jQuery(".mdf_calendar").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');
jQuery(".mdf_calendar").datepicker("option", "showAnim", 'fadeIn');
//+++
jQuery(".mdf_calendar").each(function() {
    var mktime=jQuery(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val();
    var date = new Date(mktime*1000);
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(date));
});
```

}

You saves data in hidden inputs, and load in them when page loading, so in PHP code you get mktime always and do not need to think about data format, you can set it in js as you want (in example inline)
PHP:

[image: html+php code of date picker]